# IndexedDB Index - Another storage on disk (concerning for high offline storage apps)

Tags: indexeddb

As per the Mozilla documentation -

> An index is a specialized object store for looking up records in
>   another object store, called the referenced object store. The index is
>   a persistent key-value storage where the value part of its records is
>   the key part of a record in the referenced object store.

If I understand correct then it means that if an index is created on an object store and around 10 MB data is stored in that object store then essentially 20 MB of the disk space will be occupied - 10 MB by main or referenced object store and 10 MB by index's specialized object store.

If this is true then creating indexes is potentially concerning for application fighting for storage capacity.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

See this quote:

> The values in the index's records are always values of keys in the
>   index's referenced object store. The keys are derived from the
>   referenced object store's values using a key path. If a given record
>   with key X in the object store referenced by the index has the value
>   A, and evaluating the index's key path on A yields the result Y, then
>   the index will contain a record with key Y and value X.

from here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#index-concept

Comment: Still not clear because it is talking about values of index's as a separate entity and not in context of reference or pointer to the main/referenced object store. Also, a para about in the website section also mentions that Index is a specialized persistent store which has a reference store, and records in the index store are automatically updated whenever referenced object store is updated. To me it looks like it is index occupies separate space on disk.

Comment: I have time constraint but I can try to create a sample application to calculate the storage with and without index, for a given data set.

Comment: If you do create a sample app, make sure you run it on different browsers as they all may implement the IndexedDB recommendations differently.